# How to disable urxvt autoscroll on output?

Tags: scrolling, urxvt, manjaro, i3-window-manager

I today installed the latest version of Manjaro i3 on my Macbook Pro late 2012. 
I have one problem: I don't like that the urxvt console is scrolling down when a program shows new output. (its rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.22 - released: 2016-01-23). 
So I found out that I can configure it in `/etc/skel/.Xresources` and I changed the line `! URxvt*scrollTtyOutput:            boolean` to
`URxvt*scrollTtyOutput:            false`. But it still does no scroll down on new input. Can some one of you help me out here? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that the question was posted a year ago, but it is at the top of my search results.

I've found and using this config:

```
URxvt*scrollTtyOutput:      false
URxvt*scrollWithBuffer:     true
URxvt*scrollTtyKeypress:    true
```

- When you are at the bottom of the output - the console scrolls down
  on new output;
- When you've scrolled a bit up - auto-scrolling on output stops;
- When you press any key - the terminal scrolls to the end and starts auto-scrolling;

It is the most comfortable configuration for me.

Comment: Do you know how to disable the scroll when mouse key is pressed (very annoying when you select something in the terminal and instead it scrolls all the way down)?